# Can we send Image file or Video file using Opendds?

Tags: image, mq, data-distribution-service, opendds

I am new to implementation of DDS. I have installed **OPENDDS-3.9** as it was open source.

my requirement is to transfer some **image** files and **video** files between publisher and subscriber. I couldn't find any sample project regarding this in internet, can any one help to get a sample code for image transfer.

And can I be suggested any other open source DDS which could be useful for my implementation.

Thank you

Rama

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question: yes, you can transfer images and videos. This, however, is not that trivial. You have to serialize your images into bytes, transmit the bytes and then on the subscriber side transform the bytes back into an image. The same goes for videos.

You may want to take a look at [Vortex OpenSlice DDS](http://www.prismtech.com/dds-community). This is a free Community Edition of DDS I personally preferred over OpenDDS. For a comparison of DDS implementations, you may want to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38220008/dds-which-one-is-recommended-opensplice-or-coredx/38376159#38376159).